# Topic Modelling: LDA , word frequency in each topic and Wordcloud

Tags: r, text, latent-semantic-indexing, tidytext, latent-semantic-analysis

Question: How can I compute and code the frequency of words in each topic?
My goal is to create 'Word Cloud' from each topic.

P.S.> I have no problem with wordcloud.

From the code,

```
  burnin <- 4000  #We do not collect this.
  iter <- 4000
  thin <- 500
  seed <-list(2017,5,63,100001,765)
  nstart <- 5
  best <- TRUE
  #Number of topics: 
  k <- 4
  LDA_results <-LDA(DTM,k, method="Gibbs", control=list(nstart=nstart,
                           seed = seed, best=best, 
                           burnin = burnin, iter = iter, thin=thin))
```

Thank you
(I try to make the question as concise as possible, so if you need further details, I can add more.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a wordcloud for each topic, what you want are the top terms for each topic, i.e., the most probable words to be generated from each topic. This probability is called `beta`; it's the per-topic-per-word probability. The higher this probability beta is, the higher the probability that that word is generated from that topic.

You can get out the `beta` probabilities in a tidy data frame from your LDA topic model using `tidy` from tidytext. Let's look at an example dataset and fit a model using just two topics.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(topicmodels)

data("AssociatedPress")
ap_lda <- LDA(AssociatedPress, k = 2, control = list(seed = 1234))
```

You've fit the model now! Now, we can get out the probabilities.

```r
ap_topics <- tidy(ap_lda, matrix = "beta")

ap_topics
#> # A tibble: 20,946 x 3
#>    topic       term         beta
#>    <int>      <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1     1      aaron 1.686917e-12
#>  2     2      aaron 3.895941e-05
#>  3     1    abandon 2.654910e-05
#>  4     2    abandon 3.990786e-05
#>  5     1  abandoned 1.390663e-04
#>  6     2  abandoned 5.876946e-05
#>  7     1 abandoning 2.454843e-33
#>  8     2 abandoning 2.337565e-05
#>  9     1     abbott 2.130484e-06
#> 10     2     abbott 2.968045e-05
#> # ... with 20,936 more rows
```

They are all mixed up there. Let's use dplyr to get the top most probable terms for each of the topics.

```r
ap_top_terms <- ap_topics %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  top_n(200, beta) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(topic, -beta)
```

You can now use this to make a wordcloud (with some reshaping). The `beta` probability is what you want to correspond to how big the words are.

```r
library(wordcloud)
library(reshape2)

ap_top_terms %>%
  mutate(topic = paste("topic", topic)) %>%
  acast(term ~ topic, value.var = "beta", fill = 0) %>%
  comparison.cloud(colors = c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4"),
                   max.words = 100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Julia! I am studying your code and the code from the gentleman below.... thank you!

Comment: Could you please give me some guidance how to plot wordcloud from matrix "Beta". The thickness is in frequency in my code.
          wordcloud(words = d$term, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

Answer (score 1):

Take a subset of your `DTM` according to each topics' words (`dtm[,topterms]`) and take the column sums (`slam::col_sums`) of the subsetted document term matrix. E.g.:

```
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
txt <- c(world="Hello hello world world world foo", foo="foo foo bar fizz")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(VCorpus(VectorSource(txt)))
lda <- LDA(dtm, control = list(alpha = 0.1), k = 2)
freqlst <- lapply(
  terms(lda, thres=.2, simplify=F), 
  function(topterms) slam::col_sums(dtm[,topterms])
)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
invisible(lapply(freqlst, function(x) 
  wordcloud(names(x), x, min.freq = 0)
))
```

Comment: Hi LukeA  just a quick reply.... Thank you for the reply. I will try it and get back to you later.

Comment: @Schatchawan No worries.